# Different object with same identifier was already associated with the session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have error, when try to update 'Photo':

```
  Photo photo = photoRepository.findById(id);
  List<Photo> photos = user.getPhotos();
  user.setPhotos(photos.add(photo));      
  userRepository.update(user);
```

It shows follow error:

```
  Different object with same identifier was already associated with the session
```

It seems, different object with same identifier (first: photo in first row, second: photo inside user.getPhotos()).

So, I can't update my user.
How I can avoid this Error?

userRepository:

```
tx = session.beginTransaction();
user = (User) session.get(User.class, id);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: You are using Spring, why are you manually managing your transactions? You should never get a collection and add objects to it like that. You are leaking internal state. You should have an `addPhoto` method on your `User` which adds the `Photo` to the collection and which also does `Photo.setUser` assuming it is a bi-directional relation.

Comment: sorry, i changed to user.setPhotos(photos.add(photo));

Comment: and I already have photo.setUser(). What you mean manually managing your transactions? Do you have alternative way to do that?

Comment: Which is even worse... You should allow for setting the internal collection externally, that is especially dangerous with managed collections.

Comment: And you should read the comments...

Comment: `user.setPhotos(photos.add(photo));` Could you please elaborate on this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is flawed, when managing bi-direction relationships in an ORM world your should never allow for external modifications of internal state. Currently you are having a service method that is pulling out the list of photos from the user and add a new one. With this you are only setting 1 side of the relationship. You should also call `setUser` on the `Photo` object.

```
Photo photo = photoRepository.findById(id);
List<Photo> photos = user.getPhotos();
photo.setUser(user);
user.setPhotos(photos.add(photo));      
userRepository.update(user);
```

However this code is error prone and should be inside the `User` object  next to that you shouldn't allow for `setPhotos` to be called at all as that potentially destroys all correct relations.

```
public class User {

    public Set<Photo> getPhotos() {
        // Unmodifiable to protect internal state.
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(this.photos);
    }
    // No setPhotos!

    public void addPhoto(Photo photo) {
       photo.setUser(this);
       this.photos.add(photo);
    }
}
```

Assuming your `Photo` is in the same package as `User` the `setUser` could be package visible (i.e. no `public` or `protected` on the `setUser` method).

Now in your code you can simply do

```
Photo photo = photoRepository.findById(id);
user.addPhoto(photo);
userRepository.update(user);
```

No need to make it more complex and the logic for adding a photo is now nicely encapsulated and testable.